# How to include OpenSSL in C program in Windows For Codeblocks

Tags: c, openssl, codeblocks

I am using https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/blob/master/OpenSSL/v3.1/OpenSSL-3.1.3-Win-pc064.zip pre-packaged OpenSSL library and have put it in `C:\openssl\3.1.3` directory. In my C program when I add

`#include <openssl/sha.h>`

It gives below error

`fatal error: openssl/sha.h: No such file or directory|`

I have attached Screenshot below what is my settings now... I have these

```
-pthread
-I C:\openssl\3.1.3\include
-L C:\openssl\3.1.3\lib
-lcrypto
```

in my Other linker options field. I must be missing a very silly thing, please do point it out and help me setting up OpenSSL in Windows.

[image: Compiler Setting]

Comment: Missing headers are reported by the compiler, not by the linker. Option `-I` is used to specify include folders for the compiler. Why did you put it in linker options? Put it in compiler options instead. The linker is not used at all if compilation already fails.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/m8dj5J2j9xPP I have added it under compiler options, now it shows this error -> `undefined reference to 'SHA256'`

My code example : `SHA256(str, strlen((char *)str), hash);`